# Magento 2: What is purpose of .php_cs file?

Tags: magento2, php, testing

The `.php_cs` file can be found on the root of the Magento installation.
I'd like to know how can I use it as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The **PHP Coding Standards Fixer** tool fixes most issues in your code when you want to follow the PHP coding standards as defined in the PSR-1 and PSR-2 documents and many more.
>
> If you are already using a linter to identify coding standards problems in your code, you know that fixing them by hand is tedious, especially on large projects. This tool does not only detect them, but also fixes them for you.

You can see how to use using this command below on the root of your installation:

```
php -f vendor/bin/static-review.php
```

You will see this screen:

[image: Static Review]

You can setup in your project using this command below, then when you use a command git it'll be executed.

```
php -f vendor/bin/static-review.php hook:install dev/tools/Magento/Tools/StaticReview/pre-commit .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

**Sample**

[image: Git hook static check]

References:

https://www.sitepoint.com/writing-php-git-hooks-with-static-review/

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/506

https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

Comment: that is seems  nice answer:)